# Implementing respond_to? method with active_record-acts_as gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using the [`active_record-acts_as`](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as) gem to implement multi-table inheritance in my rails app. This gem helps a child class act like the parent class, so it responds to a parent class's methods. I want to make the parent class also respond to the child class's methods because it simplifies routing.

So far I have:

```
class ParentClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  actable as: :assetable

  def method_missing_with_specific(method, *args, &block)
    # specific is the associated child class instance
    if specific.respond_to?(method)
      specific.send(method, *args, &block)
    else
      method_missing_without_specific(method, *args, &block)
    end
  end

  alias_method_chain :method_missing, :specific

  def is_a_with_specific?(type)
    if assetable_type.constantize == type
      true
    else
      is_a_without_specific?(type)
    end
  end

  alias_method_chain :is_a?, :specific
end
```

This works great, but I'm having trouble implementing the `respond_to?` method to go with the `method_missing` one.

I tried:

```
def respond_to?(method, private=false)
  super || specific.respond_to?(method, private)
end
```

and:

```
def respond_to_with_specific?(method, private=false)
  if specific.respond_to?(method, private)
    true
  else
    respond_to_without_specific?(method, private)
  end
end

alias_method_chain :respond_to?, :specific
```

Both of these methods result in my tests failing with:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 SystemStackError:
   stack level too deep
 # /Users/blueye/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286
 # 
 #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
 #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
 #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
```

Clearly I am causing some sort of infinite recursion when interacting with `ActiveRecord`, but I'm not sure how.

How can I implement `respond_to?` in this case?

Update:

I found the following code in the gem:

```
def respond_to?(name, include_private = false)
  super || acting_as.respond_to?(name)
end
```

Which seems like it would create some sort of circular logic where each class keeps delegating `respond_to?` to the other. I tried overriding this method in the child classes, but calling `super` seems to just delegate to the included method from the gem module.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `respond_to?` inside your `respond_to_with_specific?` method, hence infinite recursion.

Since Child classes should have all the methods of the Parents class *plus* some methods, you should be able to just do:

```
def respond_to_with_specific?(method, private=false)
  specific.respond_to_without_specific?(method, private)
end
```

Comment: This still seems to give me an infinite loop.